# Can you change ROI (region of Interest) for stereo camera without recalibrating?

Tags: ros, stereo, stereo-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've built a high-resolution stereo camera (two Prosilica GC2450-C's), and I'm setting a region of interest that needs to be changeable without manually recalibrating the stereo camera. I'd like to be able to take full-frame pictures (no region of interest), identify where in my image is my target, and then set a smaller region of interest onto the target so that I can increase my framerate. Do I need to recalibrate the stereo setup when I change the region of interest? The camera intrinsics and rigid-body-displacement between the cameras won't change at all when I change the region of interest, but I'm wondering if changing the image size will require a manual (checkboard) recalibration. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63537/can-you-change-roi-(region-of-interest)-for-stereo-camera-without-recalibrating?/) by [rdbrewer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4981/rdbrewer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing ROI should *not* affect calibration.

See [REP-0104](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0104.html#raw-and-rectified-roi).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0